# reading inputs from input file, keep getting infinite loop

Tags: c, input

after tirelessly looking for an explanation I've decided to ask the greats at stackoverflow. So I'm currently trying to read each input line by line from a file called data.txt. The program works perfectly fine using simple scanf and such, but when I want to read input values from a file the program only reads the first 3 lines of the txt and it keeps repeating in an infinite loop. My code is shown below. I kept out the majority of my code in case others may be tempted to use it. Program will just read 1, 12, 0 infinitely. sample data.txt file is shown below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

// Global variables
char *Hstring = NULL;
int maxLength, parity;
char *temp = NULL;
int userChoice = 0;


void option1() {
    // User inputs length and even or odd parity bit 
    printf("\n*** Maximum Code Length: %d", maxLength);
    //scanf("%d",&maxLength);
    printf("\n*** Parity: %d", parity);
    //scanf("%d",&parity);
   // allocate memory for hamming string based on maximum length and 
   //size of character element
    Hstring = (char *)malloc(maxLength * sizeof(char));
    return;
}

void option2() {
    /* declare local vars */
    int aLength, k, parBits, parValue, errorPos, i, j;
    /* prompt for hamming code as a "string"*/
    printf("\nEnter the Hamming Code: ");
    scanf("%s", Hstring);
    temp = Hstring;
    aLength = strlen(Hstring);
    parBits = ceil(log(aLength) / log(2));
}

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR OPENING THE FILE\n");
    }
    fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &userChoice, &maxLength, &parity);
    //end file open

    while (userChoice != 3) {
        printf("\nEnter Selection: %d", userChoice);
        //scanf("%d",&userChoice);
        switch (userChoice) {
        case 1:option1();
            break;
        case 2:option2();
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("\n*** Program Terminated Normally\n");
            break;
        default: printf("invalid input please input another number\n\n");
            break;
        }
    }
    /* print out menu, prompt for choice, and call appropriate procedure
    until user quits */

    return 1;
}
```

SAMPLE data.txt

```
1
12
0
2
1000
1
```

Code starts to loop when it reads the third integer(parity) in option1()

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm, why are you reading `userChoice` from the file to begin with? Is that where the user put the input?

Comment: Yes sir, its supposed to act like a main menu, and from there it goes to either option1() or option2() depending on input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53475412/4386427 is correctly describing the problem, i.e. that you have an endless loop because `userChoice` is only read once.

Here is a suggestion for a fix.

```
int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR OPENING THE FILE\n");
    }


    while (userChoice != 3) {

        // Check that exactly 3 items are read from the file.
        // If not terminate the program
        if (fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &userChoice, &maxLength, &parity) != 3) {
            printf("Illegal input from file or EOF. Terminating program\n");
            break;
        }

        switch (userChoice) {
        case 1:option1();
            break;
        case 2:option2();
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("\n*** Program Terminated Normally\n");
            break;
        default: printf("invalid input please input another number\n\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never modify `userChoice` in your while loop, so it's gonna loop forever.

Anyways, even if you were using `fscanf` in the while loop, and therefore reading the whole file until you find `userChoice == 3`, it's a bad idea to have your loop termination condition only depending on the content of a file, you should also check the result of `fscanf` for termination of the file. Your example data would still loop forever because it contains no `3`.

Comment: sorry may have mis-worded what i said, the userChoice will either be 1, 2, or 3 in this particular case (i have error check in my real code)

Comment: @JohnnyCage300 This answer still seems correct. You only read `userChoice` once (and it gets the value 1) so this `while (userChoice != 3)` will be an endless loop

Comment: @4386427 when it reads the text file, it reads the first line which is 1, and that takes them to option1() where it asks for maxLength, maxLength is read from the second line of the text file(12), but when i get to parity(0 - Line 3 of text file) it takes me right back to the beginning of the text file and it just repeats 1, 12, 0 infinitely. So lets say after we input the parity(Line3 of txt file) , theres a 2 up next in the text file, how would i be able to get that instead of it looping back to 1

Comment: @JohnnyCage300 it does not "take you back" to the beginning of the text file. It's just that you read only the first 3 params once and then print them infinitely.

Comment: @JohnnyCage300 Your description is wrong. You don't read anything in `option1()`. It is all commented out. Instead you read `userChoice, maxLength, parity` in main before the loop

Comment: @JohnnyCage300 yes, and after that you **never** change `userChoice` so you have an endless loop

Comment: Yes but you call this only once, before your while loop

Comment: @JohnnyCage300 Maybe you intended to have this line `fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &userChoice, &maxLength, &parity);` inside the while loop? That would make more sense. However, since your file doesn't contain `3` you'll still have an endless loop.

Comment: appreciate all the help btw!

Comment: @4386427 you hit the hammer on the nail my friend, that's what was causing the issue. Thanks again!!